# There are erros when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, react-rails

My rails app uses react-rails and I deployed my project to Heroku. And it was finished successfully. But I can't connect the project on Heroku. It shows error page. So I have checked heroku logs.

```
2017-09-23T15:11:19.654651+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 31.200.230.123 at 2017-09-23 15:11:19 +0000
2017-09-23T15:11:19.710323+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DashboardsController#show as HTML
2017-09-23T15:11:20.013683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=rockcms.herokuapp.com request_id=5c8bebb0-fc0b-4af3-8721-006a1f9829d1 fwd="31.200.230.123" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=366ms status=500 bytes=1733 protocol=https
2017-09-23T15:11:20.002369+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 292ms  
2017-09-23T15:11:20.008529+00:00 app[web.1]: ExecJS::ProgramError (ReferenceError: React is not defined):
2017-09-23T15:11:20.011167+00:00 app[web.1]: (execjs):35:12442
2017-09-23T15:11:20.011168+00:00 app[web.1]: (execjs):43:14
```

And I think,the error occurs because of react. I need correct advice.
And if you need some information, I will show them.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it working in local environment???

Comment: Yes, it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Import these above the file where your react code resides

```
import React from "react"; 
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

Comment: I've added the code to all files which use react. But same error    :(

Answer (score 0):

either need imports as stated above or you need to execute npm install on your production server

Comment: Actually, I don't have package.json file in the project. The project includes react-rails(https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) gem.